# Graphql query for unconnected data

Tags: graphql

For sake of example, let's say I have apples and oranges as vertices in my graph, with no relationship between them (and no viable root vertex that could be used that would have apples and oranges linked to it). Is there a single Graphql query I can write to return both the apples and oranges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each operation in GraphQL (`query`, `mutation` and `subscription`) is mapped to an individual object type in the schema. These are known as [root operation types](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Root-Operation-Types). A root operation type can define any number of fields and each field serves as the entry point to the rest of your schema. So we could have a `Query` type that looks like this:

```
type Query {
  apples: [Apple]
  oranges: [Orange]
}
```

With [the exception of subscriptions](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Single-root-field), there is no limit to how many of these root fields you can request within a single operation. So given the above type definition, you can make a query like:

```
query {
  apples {
    variety
  }
  oranges {
    countryOfOrigin
  }
}
```